# How to get followed javascripts name in HTTP request using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to retrieve executed javaScript names from some web page.

Is there a way in Node.js using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module or another?

```
request.get('http://google.com', function(err, res, body){ 
     ... console.log(res.executedScriptNames);
})
```

[image: how to get followed scripts name]

Comment: You could use a DOM parser to find the script tags.  That would take care of all statically inserted script tags, but wouldn't find script tags that are inserted via Javascript when the page actually runs in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out all the network events which return content of type javascript, using a headless browser. In the below example, I'll use [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) to fetch the events which triggered a response of type javascript on this stackoverflow question page itself. So, basically we will try to capture these events:
[image]

```
$ cat example.js

"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

address = 'http://stackoverflow.com/q/42036173/1005215';

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    if (res.contentType.match(/javascript/)) {
        console.log(res.url)
    }
};

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});

$ ./node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs example.js 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=fb1e02135f20
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=fb1e02135f20
https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=e297fe5bed6f
https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=e297fe5bed6f
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=a0fe0d0994a1
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=a0fe0d0994a1
http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
http://static.adzerk.net/ados.js
http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
http://static.adzerk.net/ados.js
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=c681521379d1
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/post-validation.en.js?v=fce27e94a6e2
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=c681521379d1
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/post-validation.en.js?v=fce27e94a6e2
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/external-editor.en.js?v=fc20a49e5703
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/external-editor.en.js?v=fc20a49e5703
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js?v=c8fdcebf5ffa
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js?v=c8fdcebf5ffa
http://engine.adzerk.net/ados?t=1486193384630&request=%7B%22Placements%22:[%7B%22A%22:22,%22S%22:8277,%22D%22:%22adzerk1757851126%22,%22AT%22:4,%22Z%22:[43]%7D,%7B%22A%22:22,%22S%22:8277,%22D%22:%22adzerk8365673
47%22,%22ATA%22:[5,17,2221],%22Z%22:[45]%7D],%22Keywords%22:%22javascript%2Cnode.js%2Crequest%22,%22Referrer%22:%22%22,%22IsAsync%22:true%7D
http://engine.adzerk.net/ados?t=1486193384630&request=%7B%22Placements%22:[%7B%22A%22:22,%22S%22:8277,%22D%22:%22adzerk1757851126%22,%22AT%22:4,%22Z%22:[43]%7D,%7B%22A%22:22,%22S%22:8277,%22D%22:%22adzerk8365673
47%22,%22ATA%22:[5,17,2221],%22Z%22:[45]%7D],%22Keywords%22:%22javascript%2Cnode.js%2Crequest%22,%22Referrer%22:%22%22,%22IsAsync%22:true%7D
http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.js
http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.js
https://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/dcmads.js
https://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/dcmads.js
https://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/impl_v37.js
https://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/impl_v37.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js
https://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=AndQltTPTNQIAAAAAM1rgQICAAAAAgAAAAAcAAAAfGphdmFzY3JpcHR8bm9kZS5qc3xyZXF1ZXN0fAAPFwvS4zhP5nDC&lw=460&zc=25&pf=9
https://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?omni=AndQltTPTNQIAAAAAM1rgQICAAAAAgAAAAAcAAAAfGphdmFzY3JpcHR8bm9kZS5qc3xyZXF1ZXN0fAAPFwvS4zhP5nDC&lw=460&zc=25&pf=9
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20170130/r20110914/activeview/osd_listener.js
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20170130/r20110914/activeview/osd_listener.js
https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/akyi97Q8.js
https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/akyi97Q8.js
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/bg/Ro40R1A0hMb7Dr8cRp0qxN1ZFlZvSN3Q_N9oN3lQJ6s.js
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/bg/Ro40R1A0hMb7Dr8cRp0qxN1ZFlZvSN3Q_N9oN3lQJ6s.js
```